# Custom mapping for into_group_map in rust

Tags: rust

I have the following data structure

```
pub struct FileContent{
    version: u16,
    fileTypes: Vec<FileVersion>
}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum FileVersion {
    Cats(String, Vec<Definition>),
    Dogs(Vec<Definition>),
    Birds(Vec<Definition>),
}

pub struct Definition {
..
}
```

And I want to parse it into a HashMap<string, Vec> where only FileVersion::Cats are included.
I have the following code:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;
    
let x = config
    .fileTypes
    .iter()
    .filter_map(|voc| match voc {
        FileVersion::Cats(s, v) => Some((s, v)),
        _ => None,
    })
    .into_group_map();
```

Which gives me a HashMap<string, Vec<Vec>>, but there is really no need for the double vector structure. How can I map this so I get HashMap<string, Vec>?

Comment: I don't think `Itertools`'s `into_group_map` will do that. It states "Return a `HashMap` of keys mapped to `Vec`s of values."  — https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.into_group_map. 

In the given example, the first element of each `Tuple` is used as key and the second element will be added to that key as value. As stated, I'd opt for `FromIterator`, you could then perhaps even drop the `Itertools` dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would using [`std::iter::FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#tymethod.from_iter) be an option?

The following might create the structure that you're looking for:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::iter::FromIterator;

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
pub enum FileVersion {
    Cats(String, Vec<Definition>),
    Dogs(Vec<Definition>),
    Birds(Vec<Definition>),
}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
pub struct Definition;

fn main() {
    let file_types = vec![
        FileVersion::Cats(String::from("A"), vec![Definition, Definition]),
        FileVersion::Dogs(vec![Definition]),
        FileVersion::Cats(String::from("B"), vec![Definition]),
        FileVersion::Birds(vec![Definition]),
    ];

    let my_map = HashMap::<_, _>::from_iter(file_types.into_iter().filter_map(|voc| match voc {
        FileVersion::Cats(s, v) => Some((s, v)),
        _ => None,
    }));
}
```

The value for `my_map` should then equal `{"A": [Definition, Definition], "B": [Definition]}`.